# Current directory is invalid when running batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

This is my run.bat file:

```
@echo off
start compactau.exe
"c:\program files\java\jre7\bin\java" -Xms512m -Xmx768m -cp jio.jar;log4j-1.2.9.jar;auagent.jar Auagent auagent.conf
Pause
```

When I run this file, I get the error `the current directory is invalid`. I uninstalled and reinstalled Java, then changed my Java location to `c:\java\bin\java` and adjusted my batch file like this:

```
@echo off
start compactau.exe
"c:\java\bin\java" -Xms512m -Xmx768m -cp jio.jar;log4j-1.2.9.jar;auagent.jar Auagent auagent.conf
Pause
```

But I still get the `the current directory is invalid`. How is this possible when I created the destination and folder name?

```
@echo off
start /D DBServerSimulator ./DBServerSimulator.exe
start /D DetectCheatServer ./DetectCheatServer/DetectCheatServerR
start /D ServerGuarder ./ServerGuarder/ServerGuarder.exe
start /D ManagerServer ManagerServer/ManagerServerR
start /D GateServer ./GateServer/Gate
start /D LocalSaveServer LocalSaveServer/LocalSaveServerR
start /D ShareMemProc ./ShareMemProc/ShareMemProcR
start /D GameServer ./GameServer/Line.exe 
Start /D Auagent run.bat!
```

is my start.bat the last thing to start is my run.bat it starts the whole server boots up but because java wont kick in i get errors which i cant post coz it's image file only and i cant post them due to being a new user lol

Comment: (1) Please post your error message. Test your java installation by running `java` without parameters. It should print usage message. Then run `java -version`. This should print version info. Please let us know whether this works.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't specify a [title](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to start. Use quotes for an empty title

```
start "" compactau.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks it is missing the directory where compactau.exe is stored.

Can you just add a line as

```
cd <path where the compactau.exe is stored>

e.g. cd c:\personal\exe_dir
```

before "start compactau.exe" so it can use the directory?

However the question is not clear enough in which line you get the error. Can you please mention it or post the error log?

and what are you going to do with `Auagent auagent.conf`, are they parameters to main method() ?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try by setting the path first before you run your java command?

You need not provide the whole absoulute path for using `java` command.